# copy paste screenshot in summernote and upload as file

Tags: php, image, upload

I am using summernote text editor with PHP, I can drag and drop image files .png, .jpeg and can able to upload image and get returned image path and display image.

I do use codeigniter and below is used for validation of image,

```
$config['upload_path']   = './uploads/parts/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size']      = '2000';
$config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
```

When i drag drop png extension file, it works perfectly, and below is request paylod, expected to run because file already have extension of png.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZoezKRGNH5LYW3oL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="2016-06-17_12-53-01.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryZoezKRGNH5LYW3oL--
```

But when i take screenshot and simply copy it, and paste in editor it goes as BLOB and my validation throw error,

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryagedeUpo2DrEPCbg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryagedeUpo2DrEPCbg--
```

And because of no extension of file, it throw error `The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

How can we send copy paste image as .png or which extension should i allowed for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did modified my upload JS,

earlier one was like below,

```
data = new FormData();
data.append("userfile", files[0])
```

So with this it will take filename as per attached file name example myfilename.png,

now to remove dependency of file name, i changed code to below,

```
data = new FormData();
data.append("userfile", files[0], upload.png)
```

So now all copy paste image and drag drop image file will always go as upload.png. even blob will be named as upload.png.

Reference -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 0):

Go to `application/config/mimes.php`

```
'gif'   =>  'image/gif',
'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'jpe'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png'),
```

> If its fail still `echo pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` and check the extension and to mimes

Read [CodeIgniter Image and File Upload in Formget.com](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/)

Comment: this is same as my mimes file, but how to allow that blob file? see filename="blob" its without extension.

Comment: @rjcode to allow all, add this `$config['allowed_types'] = '';`

Comment: i did it another way, and i don't want everything as allowed, what i did is changed filed name to always upload.png, i will post my answer here

Comment: that's what i mentioned you in my answer

Comment: i modified JS, not PHP controller.